# Conditionally add a product to a new order created programmatically in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

I'm new in the community and using Woocommerce, I'm trying to split an order according to a specific delivery date, when I run the code using `product_type` as the condition to add the product to the new order it works fine, but what I really need is set the condition for a specific delivery date, I used a function to save specific fields of products into `order_itemmeta` DB (because that fields into products sometimes need to be changed) to do that I used this (I found examples here in Stackoverflow and combine like 3 or 4 answers):

```
// Save and display "Custom Field for Simple Products" on order items everywhere
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'action_wc_checkout_create_order_line_item_2', 10, 4 );
function action_wc_checkout_create_order_line_item_2( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    // Get the Custom Field
    $calories = $values['data']->get_meta( 'acf-calories' );

    if( ! empty( $calories ) ) {
        // Save it and display it
        $item->update_meta_data( __( 'acf-calories', 'woocommerce' ), $calories );
    }   
     $delivery_date = $values['data']->get_meta( 'acf-delivery_date' );

    if( ! empty( $delivery_date ) ) {
        // Save it and display it
        $item->update_meta_data( __( 'acf-delivery_date', 'woocommerce' ), $delivery_date );
    }
}
    
    // Change displayed label for specific custom order item meta keys
add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key', 'filter_wc_order_item_display_meta_key', 10, 3 );
function filter_wc_order_item_display_meta_key( $display_key, $meta, $item ) {

    // Change displayed label for specific order item meta key
    if( $item->get_type() === 'line_item' ) {
        if( $meta->key === 'acf-calories' ) {
            $display_key = __("Calories", "woocommerce");
        }
        if( $meta->key === 'acf-delivery_date' ) {
            $display_key = __("Delivery Date", "woocommerce");
        }
    }
    return $display_key;
}
```

And then, for split the orders I use this code (also I found it here, in the answer to the Split orders with backorders)

```
function action_woocommerce_checkout_order_processed( $order_id, $posted_data, $order ) {
       $order = wc_get_order( $order_id);
       $new_order = wc_create_order();
       $delivery_date = '05-30-2023';
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        // Get product
        $product = $item->get_product($product_id);
        $delivery = $item->get_meta('acf-delivery_date');
        $product_quantity = $item->get_quantity();
        $parent_id = $item->get_meta('parent_id');
        $product_string = $item->get_meta('wooco_ids');
    
        //Here I need to add the condition, when I use simple as condition product it works but I need to set a specific delivery date as the condition
    if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ))  {
        
            $new_order->add_product( $product, $product_quantity );
       } 
    }   
    
        
        // Obtain necessary information
        // Get address
        $address = array(
            'first_name' => $order->get_billing_first_name(),
            'last_name'  => $order->get_billing_last_name(),
            'email'      => $order->get_billing_email(),
            'phone'      => $order->get_billing_phone(),
            'address_1'  => $order->get_billing_address_1(),
            'address_2'  => $order->get_billing_address_2(),
            'city'       => $order->get_billing_city(),
            'state'      => $order->get_billing_state(),
            'postcode'   => $order->get_billing_postcode(),
            'country'    => $order->get_billing_country()
        );

        // Get shipping
        $shipping = array(
            'first_name' => $order->get_shipping_first_name(),
            'last_name'  => $order->get_shipping_last_name(),
            'address_1'  => $order->get_shipping_address_1(),
            'address_2'  => $order->get_shipping_address_2(),
            'city'       => $order->get_shipping_city(),
            'state'      => $order->get_shipping_state(),
            'postcode'   => $order->get_shipping_postcode(),
            'country'    => $order->get_shipping_country()
        );
        
        // Get order currency
        $currency = $order->get_currency();

        // Get order payment method
        $payment_gateway = $order->get_payment_method();
        
        // Required information has been obtained, assign it to the 'backorder' order
        // Set address
        $new_order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
        $new_order->set_address( $shipping, 'shipping' );

        // Set the correct currency and payment gateway
        $new_order->set_currency( $currency );
        $new_order->set_payment_method( $payment_gateway );

        // Calculate totals
        $new_order->calculate_totals();

        // Set order note with original ID
        $new_order->add_order_note( 'Automated backorder. Created from the original order ID: ' . $order_id );

        $new_order->update_status( 'pending' );
    }

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 10, 3 );
```

The thing is, that I need to use the field 'acf-delivery_date' as the condition to add the products to the new order, I've been looking for a way to make it work, but still, I don't find it.

I tried many times to change the condition but still doesn't worikng.

For example:

```php
if ( $product( 'acf-delivery_date' => '05-30-2023')) ) {
  $new_order->add_product( $product, $product_quantity );
}
```

But it didn't work, also I used:

```php
if ( $item( 'acf-delivery_date' => '05-30-2023')) ) {
  $new_order->add_product( $product, $product_quantity );
}
```

```php
if ( $product( 'acf-delivery_date' == '05-30-2023')) ) {
  $new_order->add_product( $product, $product_quantity );
}
```

```php
if ( $item( 'acf-delivery_date' == '05-30-2023')) ) {
  $new_order->add_product( $product, $product_quantity );
}
```

I really need to figure out how to do it, thanks in advance.

Comment: **1)** Why do you partly use the ACF plugin while your question consists of custom code anyway, why not provide the field to link the date to the product also via custom code as opposed to an extra plugin. **2)** As you know, an order generally consists of several products. What if, for example, product A contains a different date than product B? do you want to create a separate order per different date or how do you see that?

Comment: Hi, 7uc1f3r thanks for your comment, Answer 1) I don't know how to link the date to the product via custom code I'm using WPC Composite Products and the result in a order is that Parent Product get a field named "Wooco_ids" with a string like this: 37/4/4v5 where the first numbers (37) are the product ID of the child products, and the child products get a field named: Wooco_parent_id with parent product id, so, I need child products to get the same date that the parent product but only on order items, because child products could be components of another parent product with another date

Comment: Answer 2) yes, I want to create a separate order for every different date, that's my goal, for now I'm creating every delivery date order one by one via custom code, I hope to learn how to do everything with code, any help or comment will be fully appreciated, thank you in advance